# Recursive bin packing algorithm won't scale

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, stack-overflow

I completed an assignment whose specs require:

- Recursive solution
- Capacity <= 100
- values.length <= 25
- Only parameters are capacity and index
- Repetition of values is allowed

I've spent hours reading up on bin packing and knapsack problems.

The following works but is very inefficient.  I get a stack overflow with a dozen or so values.  Very inefficient, doesn't scale and I don't know where to begin.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Yes, it is an academic assignment, but I'd rather flush out the problems than just give up and earn a B.

```
public void calculateCombinations(int capacity, int index) {
    count++;
    if(index < values.length) {
        if(values[index] <= capacity) {
            currentSolution.addLast(index);
            if(values[index] == capacity)
                flushSolution();
            else
                capacity -= values[index];
        }
        calculateCombinations(capacity, index + 1);
    } else
        if(currentSolution.peekLast() != null)
            calculateCombinations(capacity + values[currentSolution.peekLast()], currentSolution.removeLast() + 1);
}
```

Comment: i'd suggest reading about dynamic programming and memoization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key heuristic to bin packing problems is to always pack the most awkward (largest) item first. For example, if you are packing a moving truck, you put the piano in first, then worry about the smaller stuff later. The idea is to maximize your flexibility.

Another technique is what I call "bracketing". Say you are looking for two numbers that sum to 50 and you have a list like { 2, 3, 9, 18, 24, 29, 37, 45 }. You don't have to check every combination because you cannot have two values over 25 or under 25. You only have to check numbers from each side of the list, ie, 45+2, 45+3, 45+9, STOP, next number, 37+2, 37+3, etc. This is bracketing. By creating a set of rules and bracketing around a mean, you only need to check a tiny fraction of the possible combinations.

Bin packing is a search problem because in many cases because you can't enumerate every possible combination. It's like chess; you can't calculate every possible move, you are just trying to find a good one.